# What is the best way to convert docx or doc file into txt in java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried to find a good way to convert but all off them not working with all the external jars that I'm required to add. 
Is there any one who knows easy / possible solution?

Comment: have tried with apache POI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is not.
a doc(x) file can contain other than plain-text content, while a txt file can't.

what you could do, if you only need the text, is to use apache poi to read all the text from your doc(x) file, and a basic FileWriter to write it to a txt file.